# Unable to format bootstrap css with Angular tags

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, nrwl-nx

I have added bootstrap via `npm install --save bootstrap` command and
I have the following Angular component:
navigation.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
            <li class="nav-header">
                <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                        <span class="block m-t-xs font-bold">Example user</span>
                        <span class="text-muted text-xs block">menu <b class="caret"></b></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="login.html">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="logo-element">
                    IN+
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main view</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="minor.html"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Minor view</span> </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

When I start the application the source is displayed at such:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ws-root _nghost-pqf-c14="" ng-version="9.0.0">
            <ws-navigation _ngcontent-pqf-c14=""> <!--- ISSUE HERE --->
                <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-default navbar-static-side">
```

Since ws-root and ws-navigation tags are placed between div#id tag the CSS doesn't format the application correctly.

[image: Bad Format]

vs

[image: Good Format]

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do so ws-root and ws-navigation tags are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use something like that

```
ws-root,ws-navigation{
  display:contents;
}
```

where `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself